# Texture Packer full path to the subimage

Tags: libgdx, texturepacker

In the book I found during reading next text:

"If the TexturePacker cannot fit all the subimages into a single texture, it will automatically split them up into several texture atlases. However, there is a chance that the subimages are distributed in an unfavorable way between these atlases if it creates two textures that will be switched between frequently, which in turn could have an impact on render performance.
LibGDX's TexturePacker has a very smart feature to tackle this type of problem. All you need to do is group the subimages in their own subfolder in assets-raw. This way TexturePacker will create one
image file per subfolder that belongs to the texture atlas. You have to use the full path to the subimage if you want to use this functionality; for example, a subimage assets-raw/items/gold_coin.png would be referenced as items/gold_coin."

Explain me please what does it mean "You have to use the full path to the subimage if you want to use this functionality". If I want to make Texture Atlas I use `TexturePacker.process(settings, "assets-raw/images", "../android/assets/images", "anyname.pack");`, how i need to put path to the subimage directly and for what is it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you have to use the folder name in the path when referencing the `TextureRegion` from the `TextureAtlas`.

So if you have an image called `image_a.png` in your `images` folder you would load that from the `TextureAtlas` normally like this:

```java
myTextureAtlas.findRegion("image_a")
```

Also if you have an image called `image_b.png` in a subfolder called `sub` then you need to specify that when loading from the `TextureAtlas`:

```java
myTextureAtlas.findRegion("sub/image_b")
```

Answer (score 0):

TexturePacker currently has 2 modi for this scenario.

One that is fully automated - it distributes sprites across as many sheets are required.

The other mode is called manual multipack: You create the sheets and simply drag & drop the folders or single sprites onto these sheets as needed.

We've decided not to create the folder based mode since you would usually get the best solution - and the file system layout will depend on the sprite usage. Our "manual" mode is way more flexible here.